# How to properly escape bash function in an alias

Tags: bash, awk, pipe, alias, zsh

I have some bash commands that I have successfully piped together:

`$> foo --color=RED | grep -Eo '(v[1-9])'`

`$> v1`

Assume `foo` is an alias that prints out many things and I want to grab a `version number` and pipe that to another command, `bar` that gets an `id`. So I add this and it works:

`$> foo --color=RED | grep -Eo '(v[1-9])' | \
    awk '{print "bar --version="$1" --color=RED"}' | xargs -0 bash -c`

`$> ID: 1234`

**Great**. Now, I'd like to create an entry in my `.aliases` file so I can just run this like so:

`$> wombat RED`

**Problems: I cannot get this to work**

```
alias wombat='function _w() { 
    COLOR=$1; # cache the color
    foo --color=$COLOR | grep -Eo "(v[1-9])" | \
    awk '{print "bar --version=$1 --color=$COLOR"}' | xargs -0 bash -c; 
};_w'
```

The problem seems to be with how I am escaping (or not escaping) around the `awk` command. **Note:** In the `awk` command I need to reference **both** the `version number` and the `color` that I passed to the alias.

I have tried many variations but cannot seem to get it right. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Why an alias? Just create a function and call it outside

Comment: Are you saying create a bash script and alias that? So long as I can call it from anywhere in my system, that would be fine.

Comment: No, just create this function in `~/.bashrc` and call it anywhere

Comment: Someone should write a good duplicate for "How do I define an alias for a complex command?" that just shows how to use functions

Comment: The proper way to use bash aliases is *never*.

Comment: Yeah, I really did look at some of the other answers first. Sorry it didn't click for me until now. I'm now a function guy for life. Thanks!

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. `grep -Eo '(v[1-9])' |  awk '{print "bar --version="$1" --color=RED"}'` = `awk 'match($0,/v[1-9]/){print "bar --version="substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)" --color=RED"}'`. If you provided sample input and expected output I'm sure someone could show you a better way to do whatever is is you're trying to do with all those commands.

Comment: @Jeff: Why did you tag this `zsh`? It seems to be a `bash` question. Also, the alias `wombat` first creates a function and then call it. Wouldn't it make more sense to make `wombat` a function which just does what you want it to do?

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that quotes don't nest -- you can't nest a single-quoted string (the `awk` script) inside a single-quoted string (the alias definition). There are ways to get this to work, but it's much simpler to just skip the alias part entirely. Making an alias that defines a function and then immediately executes it is pointless; just define the function once, use it normally. Like this:

```
wombat() { 
    local color="$1" # cache the color
    foo --color="$color" | grep -Eo "(v[1-9])" | \
        awk -v color="$color" '{print "bar --version=" $1 " --color=" color}' | \
        xargs -0 bash -c;
}
```

Note that I also made several changes to how the color name is handled: I used a lowercase shell variable name (there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, so using lower- or mixed-case names for your own stuff is safer), I made that shell variable `local`, and I passed it in to `awk` as a variable rather than trying to embed it literally in the `awk` script. Finally, in the `awk` script, I put the references to `$1` and the `color` variable outside the quoted strings, so they'll be expanded to their values rather than used literally.

Oh, and I used the POSIX-standard syntax for function definitions, which uses `()` instead of the `function` keyword to signal that this is a function definition.

Since I don't actually have the `foo` or `bar` programs, I have not actually tested this. But as far as I can see it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Bash shell debugging so you can see how your aliases and function are interpreted before they get executed

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

There are a couple of ways to turn on debugging. One is to start a new Bash session in debug mode, `bash -x`. Another is to use enable debugging in an existing Bash session, `set -x`

Comment: This is a comment on how to debug general problems, not an answer to the question.